# Need some help to integrate Storybook into exsiting React application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am trying to integrate Storybook to my existing React application. After run npx sb@latest init command getting below error message.

```
[ESLintError: [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.cjs » eslint-config-custom" and "BaseConfig » C:\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".]
```

This is React typescript application with below package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.14.6",
  "description": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "../home/",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.2.2",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.4.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-build-info": "^0.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "9.2.6",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.76.0",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^5.0.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.13.1",
    "yup": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "local": "node ./scripts/build-info.cjs && webpack serve --port 3000",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .tsx,.ts .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .tsx,.ts . --fix",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "7.4.6",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.2.2",
    "@types/sass": "^1.43.1",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "0.0.2",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.14",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "storybook": "7.4.6",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

I need to up and run also build the storybook? As per my understanding it is related to eslint
because there's .eslintrc.cjs file there it contains
extend custom and plugin:storybook/recommended